# How can i pass data in reactstrap modal when specific button id is click?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

How can i pass data from my modal if specific button zone id is clicked? For example i have object listed below and got 2 buttons. How can i pass my Zone to respective buttons?

Here is how i define my state.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: Data,
        modal: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}


toggle(item) {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
}
```

Here's my button rendered. Two times.

```
<Button onClick={this.toggle} color="info" size="sm" block>Zone 1</Button>
<Button onClick={this.toggle} color="info" size="sm" block>Zone 2</Button>
```

Here's the data.

```
data:[{
    "Assignment": "52041",
    "Zone": "1"
},
{
    "Assignment": "52042",
    "Zone": "2"
}]
```

Comment: You can use data-attributes

Comment: Is the Button component your custom button and where exactly are you trying to use zone data

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data onClick like following.

```
class Test {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: Data,
            modal: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }
    toggle(item) {
        this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }
    render() {
        const data=[{
                "Assignment": "52041",
                "Zone": "1"
            },
            {
                "Assignment": "52042",
                "Zone": "2"
            }];
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={()=>this.toggle(data)} color="info" size="sm" block>Zone 1</Button>
                <Button onClick={()=>this.toggle(data)} color="info" size="sm" block>Zone 2</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```